# MySQL String Comparison with Percent Output

Tags: sql, mysql, string-comparison

I am trying to compare two entries of 6 numbers, each number which can either can be zero or 1 (i.e 100001 or 011101). If 3 out of 6 match, I want the output to be .5. If 2 out of 6 match, i want the output to be .33 etc.

Here are the SQL commands to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE sim
(sim_key int,
 string int);

INSERT INTO sim (sim_key, string)
VALUES (1, 111000);

INSERT INTO sim (sim_key, string)
VALUES (2, 111111);
```

My desired output to compare the two strings, which share 50% of the characters, and output 50%.

Is it possible to do this sort of comparison in SQL? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post some sample data in tabular format and desired output?

Comment: can you please explain more about the problem

Comment: Do the two numbers appear in the same row in a table, or are they from the same column in two different rows?  My feeling is that this is possible, 'how' depends on where the numbers come from. It will require a calculation within MySQL so indexes wouldn't be used - this would make it slow to query a large dataset (returning lots of rows), but OK if you are only ever comparing two numbers directly.

Comment: Looks like binary data - could you using binary/varbinary types?  Are you saving them as strings (or zero padded ints) to keep the leading zeros?

Comment: Does creating the table help explain what I am trying to do? And this is basically binary data. How would I do the comparison with binary data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL String Comparison with Percent Output (Position Very Important](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856340/mysql-string-comparison-with-percent-output-position-very-important)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns the percentage of equal 1 bits in both strings:

```
select bit_count(conv(a.string, 2, 10) & conv(b.string, 2, 10))/6*100 as percent_match
from sim a, sim b where
a.sim_key=1 and b.sim_key=2;
```

As you store your bitfields as base 2 representation converted to numbers, we first need to do conversions: `conv(a.string, 2, 10)`, `conv(b.string, 2, 10)`.

Then we keep only bits that are 1 in each field: `conv(a.string, 2, 10) & conv(b.string, 2, 10)`

And we count them: `bit_count(conv(a.string, 2, 10) & conv(b.string, 2, 10))`

And finally we just compute the percentage: `bit_count(conv(a.string, 2, 10) & conv(b.string, 2, 10)) / 6 * 100`.

The query returns `50` for `111000` and `111111`.

Here is an other version that also counts matching zeros:

```
select bit_count((conv(a.string, 2, 10) & conv(b.string, 2, 10)) | ((0xFFFFFFFF>>(32-6))&~(conv(a.string, 2, 10)|conv(b.string, 2, 10))))/6*100 as percent_match
from sim a, sim b where
a.sim_key=1 and b.sim_key=2;
```

---

Note that, while this solution works, you should really store this field like this instead:

```
INSERT INTO sim (sim_key, string)
VALUES (1, conv("111000", 2, 10));

INSERT INTO sim (sim_key, string)
VALUES (2, conv("111111", 2, 10));
```

Or to update existing data:

```
UPDATE sim SET string=conv(string, 10, 2);
```

Then this query gives the same results (if you updated your data as described above):

```
select bit_count(a.string & b.string)/6*100 as percent_match
from sim a, sim b where
a.sim_key=1 and b.sim_key=2;
```

And to count zeros too:

```
select bit_count((a.string & b.string) | ((0xFFFFFFFF>>(32-6))&~(a.string|b.string)))/6*100 as percent_match
 from sim a, sim b where
 a.sim_key=1 and b.sim_key=2;
```

(replace `6`s by the size of your bitfields)

Comment: After much analysis, I have found that isn't exactly what I want. It is important to indicate that position matter as well

Comment: This solution is supposed to take care of the positions. With which strings doesn't it work ? The `&` (bitwise-and) operator keeps only 1-bits which are at the same position in both operands. Then the `bit_count()` function just counts them. So this counts 1-bits that are in both strings, at the same position.

Comment: For example it doesn't work with the values 111000 and 101011. It returns a score of 67% instead of 50%

Comment: It should actually return 33.33% (2/6). The query in the answer returns 33.33%: Keeping bits at the same position in 111000 and 101011 gives 101000. So 2 bits are equal. Divide by 6, multiply by 100 -> 33.33%. (Note that the last query I gave in the answer works only if you also updated your data accordingly; if not, just use the first query.)

Comment: No because I want to count matched zeros as matches as well. Maybe I didn't explain that properly in my question.

Comment: Added a version which counts zeros too; note that for simplicity if works only on masks with 6 bits.

Comment: Thank you very much! I honestly wish I could pay you for this help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing them as numbers, you can do this

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT(s1.string & s2.string) / BIT_COUNT(s1.string  | s1.string)
FROM sim s1, sim s2
WHERE s1.sim_key = 1 AND s2.sim_key = 2
```

Comment: returns 0.3333 on (111000, 111111) ;-)

Comment: You are storing binary `11` as Eleven? instead of Three